# How can I populate a drop down with the value retrieved from mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dynamic, dropdown

I have two forms, one that adds data(`addData.php`) and one that retrieved and edit the added data(`editData.php`). In `addData.php` I have three drop down list (*Country*, *State*, and *City*) that is dynamic and dependent from one another. Each have their own tables in a database in which they get their data(`country_table`, `state_table` and `city_table`). The `country_table` has two fields, which is `country_id` and `country_name`, the other two tables has three fields: `state_id`, `country_id` and `state_name`. The `city_table` has a similar set up. The *Country* drop down list is populated by data from database using the following PHP code:

```
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField">Country<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-6">
      <?php
      $stmt = $country->readCountry();
      $num = $stmt->rowCount();
      if($num>0){
          echo "<select name='country' id='country-list' class='form-control style='margin-bottom: 10px'>";
          echo "<option value='0'>Select Country...</option>";
          while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              extract($row);
              echo '<option value="'.$row["country_name"].'"data-country_id="'.$row["country_id"].'">'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';
          }
          echo "</select>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField">State<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-6">
      <select name='state' id='state-list' class='form-control' style='margin-bottom: 10px'>
        <option value='0'>Select State</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField">City<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-6">
      <select name='city' id='city-list' class='form-control' style='margin-bottom: 10px'>
        <option value="0">Select City</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The other two drop down list is also populated by data from MySQL database, but this time using the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#country-list").change(function(){

var country_id=$(this).find(':selected').data('country_id');

var json_url="state_json.php?country_id=" + country_id;

jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data){

  $("#state-list").html("");
  $("#state-list").append("<option value='0'>Select State</option>");
  $("#city-list").html("");
  $("#city-list").append("<option value='0'>Select City</option>");

  jQuery.each(data, function(key, val){
      $("#state-list").append('<option value="' + val.state_name + '"data-state_id="' + val.state_id + ' ">' + val.state_name + '</option>')
  });

});

});
$("#state-list").change(function(){

var state_id=$(this).find(':selected').data('state_id');

var json_url="city_json.php?city_id=" + city_id;

jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data){

  $("#city-list").html("");
  $("#city-list").append("<option value='0'>Select City</option>");

  jQuery.each(data, function(key, val){
      $("#city-list").append("<option value='" + val.city_name + "'>" + val.city_name + "</option>")
  });

});

});
});
</script>
```

The above code, though not perfect, works for me.

Now, the problem is with `editData.php`. Supposed I added new record on database with the data I collected from `addData.php` and I wanted to update or edit that data using `edit.php`. In `editData.php` there is also three drop down list similar to `addData.php`. **The first problem** is I cannot make it work similar to `addData.php` i.e. dependent, dynamic and populated with data from database. **Second** I wanted to pre-populate the drop down list with the data from previously added data using `addData.php`. In the first drop down list which is the *Country* I am able to make it work using the code below:

```
  <div class="form-group required input-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField">Country<span class="asteriskField">*</span>  </label>
<div class="controls col-md-6">
  <?php
  $stmt = $country->readCountry();
  $num = $stmt->rowCount();
  if($num>0){
    ?>
      <select name="country" id="country-list" class="form-control" style='margin-bottom: 10px'>
      <option value='0'>Select Country...</option>
      <?php while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          extract($row); ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['country_name'];?>" data-country_id="<?php $row['country_id'];?>"

          <?php
          if($record->country==$row['country_name']) echo 'selected';?>>
           <?php echo $row["country_name"];?> </option>
    <?php  } ?>
      </select>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

This it what the `state_json.php` looks like.. similar to `city_json.php`.

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header('Content-Type: application/json');


$country_id=isset($_GET['country_id']) ? $_GET['country_id'] : die('Country ID not found.');


include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/state.php';


$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$state = new State($db);

$state->country_id=$country_id;
$stmt = $state->readState();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

And this is what `state.php` looks like

```
<?php
class State{


private $conn;
private $table_name = "state_table";

public $state_id;
public $country_id;
public $state_name;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}


public function readState(){

    $query = "SELECT state_id, country_id, state_name
            FROM " . $this->table_name . "
            WHERE country_id=:country_id
            ORDER BY state_name";


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);


    $this->country_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->country_id));

    $stmt->bindParam(":country_id", $this->country_id);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}

}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have the country_id, state_id and city_id

Not sure if this line is correct as you are passing city_id to api

```
var state_id=$(this).find(':selected').data('state_id');
var json_url="city_json.php?city_id=" + city_id;
```

In edit page load your php state_id and city_id to js as the following

```
<script>
var state_id = <?php echo $state_id ; ?>
var city_id= <?php echo $city_id; ?>
</script>
```

Then call your api when JavaScript is loaded and if state_id = your state_id make it selected

```
if(data-state_id == state_id){
    $("#state-list").append('<option value="' + val.state_name + '"data-state_id="' + val.state_id + ' " selected>' + val.state_name + '</option>');
}
else
{
    $("#state-list").append('<option value="' + val.state_name + '"data-state_id="' + val.state_id + ' ">' + val.state_name + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow, but I will try to understand your suggestion, I would use it as my basis. I will give feedback later on how it turns out. Thanks